# Limitar caracteres e tipo de caracteres

Tags: vba, excel-vba, macro

Preciso de uma ajuda.

Eu tenho uma planilha desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quero limitar quantidade de caracteres e o tipo

Na coluna segment quero limitar em 6 caracteres, se for menos que 6 ou mais que 6. Retorna a msg "Limite de caracteres não atingido"

Na coluna date quero limitar a tipo date em 8 caracteres,se for menos que 8 ou mais que 8. Retorna a msg "Limite de caracteres não atingido"

E na coluna number quero limitar a tipo numero em 4 caracteres,se for menos que 4 ou mais que 4. Retorna a msg "Limite de caracteres não atingido"

Eu comecei a escrever algo, mas não estou enxergando aonde estou errando. E sinceramente há muito tempo não escrevo codigo VBA

Não estou lembrada como selecionar a coluna e colocar a macro.

'Se não houver 4 números'
If IntTamanho <> 4 Then
MsgBox "Limite de Caracteres não Atingido ", vbCritical
Application.EnableEvents = False
Rng.ClearContents
Application.EnableEvents = True
Se alguem puder ajudar, eu já agradeço

```
Código está assim:
Sub LimitarCaractere()

Dim TRACKER As Workbook '<-- Tracker
Dim MARKET As Worksheet '<-- Aba
Dim i As Long           '<-- Linha selecionada
Dim SEGM As String      '<-- Segment
Dim FLT As Integer     '<-- Flight
Dim Ddate As Date     '<-- Date

Set TRACKER = ActiveWorkbook
Set MARKET = TRACKER.ActiveSheet
i = ActiveCell.Row

'Limita o número de cacteres na célula
If i > 6 Then
     ActiveCell = Left(ActiveCell, 6)
    MsgBox "Limite de caracteres Ultrapassado na Célula: " _
    & ActiveCell
End If
End Sub
```

Obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dados de teste

Utilizando os seguintes dados para teste:

[image: dados]

#### Inserir código de Evento

Utilizar o evento `Worksheet_Change`, em que este deverá ser colocado dentro da planilha em que os dados se encontram (MARKET).
Por Exemplo, no meu caso foi em Planilha1:

[image: Planilha1]

#### Código

O código é acionado toda vez que a planilha possui alguma alteração.

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo CleanExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim i As Long                                '<-- Linha selecionada
    Dim NumeroCaract As String, anomesdia As String
    Dim ano As Long, mes As Long, dia As Long, DiasNoMes As Long

    i = Target.Column
    'Limita o número de caracteres na coluna B
    If i = 2 Then
        NumeroCaract = Len(Target.Value)
        If NumeroCaract <> 6 Then
            MsgBox "Limite de caracteres Ultrapassado na Célula: " & Target.Address
        End If
    End If

    'Limita o número de caracteres na coluna C e verifica data
    If i = 3 Then
        'Verifica Num Caract
        NumeroCaract = Len(Target.Value)
        If NumeroCaract <> 8 Then
            MsgBox "Limite de caracteres Ultrapassado na Célula: " & Target.Address
        End If
        'Verifica Data
        anomesdia = Target.Value
        ano = CLng(Left(anomesdia, 4))
        mes = CLng(Left(Mid(anomesdia, 5), 2))
        dia = CLng(Right(anomesdia, 2))
        DiasNoMes = Day(DateSerial(ano, mes + 1, 0))

        If mes < 1 Or mes > 12 Or dia < 1 Or dia > DiasNoMes Or ano < 1 Or ano > Year(Now) Then 'Checa se não é data
            MsgBox "Não é data na Célula: " & Target.Address
        End If
    End If

    'Limita o número de caracteres na coluna F e verifica se é número
    If i = 6 Then
        'Verifica Num Caract
        NumeroCaract = Len(Target.Value)
        If NumeroCaract <> 4 Then
            MsgBox "Limite de caracteres Ultrapassado na Célula: " & Target.Address
        End If
        'Verifica Se é Número

        If Not IsNumeric(Target) Then 'Checa se é data
            MsgBox "Não é número na Célula: " & Target.Address
        End If
    End If

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

#### Explicação

- Verifica Num Caract

Este código utilizada a [Função Len](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dxsw58z6(v=vs.90).aspx) para verificar o número de caracteres na String.

[image: Exemplo Num Caract]

[image: Limite caract]

- Verifica Data

Este código Extrai cada parte da String (ano,mes e dia) e verifica se o ano não é menor do que 1 ou se é maior do que o ano atual (caso trabalhe com o futuro alterar esta parte). Se o dia é menor do que 1 ou se é maior do que os dias que aquele mês possui. Se o mês é menor do que 1 ou maior do que 12.

[image: Verificar Data]

- Verifica Se é Número

Este código utiliza a [Função IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6cd3f6w1(v=vs.90).aspx) para verificar se é número.

[image: Verifica Número]

- Verifica se a célula alterada está na coluna desejada

  `If i = 2 Then` é a condicional que verifica se é a coluna do Target, contando pelo index. Onde 1 é A, 2 é B e assim por diante.

> Note que: Caso nenhuma das condições anteriores sejam atingidas, não ocorre nada. Este código somente cria uma mensagem de Erro.

Comment: Peço desculpas pelo básico que sei, mas como posso testar o código? Eu tento executar, mas abre a janela para criar um nome na macro e não consigo

Comment: @Thais Para testar, altere os valores da planilha que você inseriu o código. Os dados estão na coluna B,C e F?

Comment: eu já fiz as alterações sim. Mas eu não consigo executar o código. Eu execute em run, abre uma janela do nome das macros e não encontro Worksheet_Change, e se eu tiro do Private tbm não funciona

Comment: @Thais Como eu disse, não é para executar desta forma. Este código utiliza eventos para ser executado. Portanto toda vez que a planilha desejada sofrer alguma alteração, esta macro é acionada. Tente inserir algum valor numa célula da Planilha em que o código foi inserido.

Comment: muito obrigada pela excelente explicação, eu consegui compreender claramente, vou testar aqui e já marco a resposta. Obrigada!!!

Comment: Eu inseri vários valores nas colunas B,C e F, salvei e abri de novo. E não alterou em nada

Comment: O código não altera, ele só verifica se estes valores estão corretos na hora de inserir, se estiver incorreto, uma mensagem aparece.

Comment: Entendi, dei até uma boa pesquisada no que é esse evento. Eu fiz vários testes e não aparece a msg. Devo estar errando em algo.

Comment: Consegui acertar aqui. Funcionou!! Muito obrigada!!