# Editar dados de um DropDown List no Excel

Tags: dropdown, excel-vba, dropdownlist, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma lista de itens em um dropdown no excel. Estes valores devem ser selecionados pelo usuário e a partir dai, edita-lo conforme solicitado. Porém, não sei como editar estes valores do dropdown. Alguém pode me ajudar? Abaixo, segue exemplo de dois itens que devem ser selecionados e em seguida, alterados pelo usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se o que você quer é verificar se é número ou data, pode usar as funções `IsNumeric()` e `IsDate()`. Já se são números e datas específicas, a utilização da validação como está sendo feito está correta.  E para editar os valores, basta escrever o valor na célula. Caso não seja esta a pergunta, poderia ser mais claro?

Comment: O que eu preciso Daniel, é que tenha informações la no dropdown predefinidas e a partir dai, o usuario selecionar e editar. Por exemplo, há a opção de Data(DD/MM/AAAA). O Usuário vai selecionar esta opção e inserir os valores dentro do () corretamente. Outro exemplo, a opção NUM(XXXXXXXX). O usuário vai selecionar esta opção e inserir os numeros no lugar dos "X's"

Comment: Refira a [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254010/75104) e veja se você tem alguma ideia de como usar as funções para verificar se é número, data e o tamanho da string inserida. Mas do modo que está sendo feito, cada campo deve ser programado separadamente. Você pode criar um formulário (userform) e validar cada TextBox separadamente. Também pode ser utilizado Regex ou WildCards... Tem inúmeras maneiras de realizar isto, pesquise um pouco e veja qual é melhor, mas você possui muitas entradas o que torna isto mais complexo...

Answer (score 1):

Vá no menu dados (1), subopção validação de dados (2), como você já tem uma lista no critério de validação a opção permitir deve estar como lista (3), edite a fonte ou o conteúdo das células nela indicadas (4).

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Em fonte, está localizado meu range da lista do dropdown

Comment: Como editarei a fonte ?

Comment: Pode mostrar o conteúdo do seu campo fonte? Acho q fica mais fácil para explicar

Comment: Editei a perguntacom minha fonte adicionada